# ESC <insertchar> is undefined

Tags: emacs, editor

I want to bind M- to a function. Here's how

```
(define-key global-map [(meta insert)] 'vi-open-line)
```

But when I press M- Emacs says `ESC <insertchar> is undefined`.

I use Emacs 23 on an Amazon EC2 linux. I work via Putty ssh client.

How can I make M- work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs is helping you. Try this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "ESC <insertchar>") 'vi-open-line)
```